# SwiftUI hide list item from list item view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

So, let's say I have a SwiftUI List and Toggle (heavily simplified):

```
List {

    Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {

        Text("Toggle")

    }

    ForEach(arr) { item in

        if isOn || !item.isComplete {

            Row(item: item)
        }

    }

}
```

Then my Row:

```
HStack {

    Button(action: {

        self.item.isComplete.toggle() // isComplete is a Boolean value

    }) {

        Text("Button")

    }

    Text(item.isComplete ? "Complete" : "Not complete")

}
```

The toggle should change the list, swapping between all items, and only non-completed items. This works perfectly. However, I want this to function so that when I press the button, the list is updated instantly and it goes away, rather than me having to re-switch the toggle. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Note that Lists are still buggy when it comes to large sets of data. Here you have an example that does what you asked. I am passing the ObservableObject, but you can also put it in the environment. That's up to you.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    @Published var arr = [Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {

            Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn) { Text("Toggle") }

            ForEach(self.model.arr.filter { model.isOn ? true : $0.isComplete }) { item in
                Row(item: item, model: self.model)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    let item: Item
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Button(action: {

                if let idx = self.model.arr.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == self.item.id }) {
                    self.model.arr[idx].isComplete.toggle()
                    self.model.isOn = false
                }

            }) {

                Text("Button")

            }

            Text(item.isComplete ? "Complete" : "Not complete")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kontiki! I'll test it and get back to you.