# SwiftUI - hide list items using Toggle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have found almost the perfect code for my needs. But there is one problem:

**I would like to use toggles in each row instead of buttons.**

Original code posted by @kontiki here: [SwiftUI hide list item from list item view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671323/swiftui-hide-list-item-from-list-item-view)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    @Published var arr = [Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {

            Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn) { Text("Toggle") }

            ForEach(self.model.arr.filter { model.isOn ? true : $0.isComplete }) { item in
                Row(item: item, model: self.model)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    let item: Item
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Button(action: {

                if let idx = self.model.arr.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == self.item.id }) {
                    self.model.arr[idx].isComplete.toggle()
                    self.model.isOn = false
                }

            }) {

                Text("Button")

            }

            Text(item.isComplete ? "Complete" : "Not complete")

        }
    }
}
```

Instead of button I have tried to use toggle like this:

```
Toggle(isOn: $item.isComplete) {
                Text("Done")
            }
```

There is this if statement inside button that I don't understand. I have tried to take this let idx declaration outside of button too to make it easier for using toggle (as I don't know how to make such complicated toggle) but this also failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: There is known issue with Toggle control update in List. Please be aware. The details are in [Problems with layout of some rows in SwiftUI list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965282/problems-with-layout-of-some-rows-in-swiftui-list) topic.**

Here is possible approach. Modified lines are marked in comments.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable { // <<
    let id = UUID()
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    @Published var arr = [Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: false), Item(isComplete: true), Item(isComplete: true)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {

            Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn) { Text("Toggle") }

            ForEach(self.model.arr.filter { model.isOn ? true : $0.isComplete }) { item in
                Row(item: self.$model.arr[self.model.arr.firstIndex(of: item)!]) // <<
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @Binding var item: Item // <<

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $item.isComplete) {
                Text("Done")
            }
            Text(item.isComplete ? "Complete" : "Not complete")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Asperi! You are e genius. It works! :) I am aware of this problem with toggles in lists. I am the person who asked this questions you linked to. I hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: I have one small problem though. `struct LocksItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
  LocksItemView(item: Item(isComplete: false))
 }
}` produces an error: Cannot convert value of type 'Item' to expected argument type 'Binding<Item>'
How should I change this line? `item: Item(isComplete: false)`

Comment: :) I missed that it was you. Try `LocksItemView(item: .constant(Item(isComplete: false)))`