# SwiftUI: Toggle for individual items of ForEach

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, toggle

Using `ForEach`, I want to create individual Toggles for each row. Right now, the `@State` binding toggles all of the items at the same time, and I can't figure out how to separate them.

In the code below, I put a hard-coded array, but it really comes from an ever-changing .json file. Therefore, I need the `ForEach` and the binding to be dynamic.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014797/swiftui-hide-list-items-using-toggle) on hiding `List` items and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965282/problems-with-layout-of-some-rows-in-swiftui-list) on problems with `List` rows were helpful, but I couldn't make the binding work for my project. I'm on day 2 trying to figure this out, and none of what I've found online addresses this specific question.

Below is a small example of my code that reproduces my challenge. The dynamic data from the array comes from a .json file.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GreekWords: Codable, Hashable {
    var greekWordArray = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Zeta"]
    // The array data comes from a dynamic .json file
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var greekWords: GreekWords
    
    @State private var wordToggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(greekWords.greekWordArray, id: \.self) { word in
                Toggle(word, isOn: $wordToggle)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

I expect this is a simple solution, so I thank you in advance for any help. Also, I would appreciate any direction you might point me to better learn SwiftUI. I've tried all the Apple tutorials and books and the 100 days of SwiftUI on HackingWithSwift.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a modifier to any specific buttons inside a ForEach loop for an array of buttons in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array)

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for your response, but the link didn't address the binding.

Comment: It’s more about the concept each row needs its own variable. Your question doesn’t have a practical solution because we don’t know how your JSON connects with the words/bools. There are a half dozen ways to connect it, we would just be guessing.

Comment: The first referenced topic answers your question exactly. You just need adapt `Item` from there to contain you json data and bool to bind to (if it is not already in json), and as you did not provide anything specific then nobody would guess how it should be.

Comment: I'm blown away by the skill, professionalism, and kindness of all the responses here. @loremipsum both you and Asperi both point out something I didn't realize: that many times and with increasing complexity, there are many ways to solve a problem. I expect that knowing the "best practice" will some with experience. I'll try to adapt your solutions, but in the meantime and for future posts, I'll include more detailed information like how the JSON data is pulled. Thank you much!

Comment: Thank you so much @Asperi See above as it applies to you too. Would you also please point me toward more ways that I can deepen my SwiftUI developing skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example code, all toggles are referencing to the same variable. So of course all toggles will always show the same state.

In the example implementation in the link you provided, it is not just an array of strings, it is an array of objects, that also contain a bool variable to control that specific item by a toggle.

UPDATE (2):

Maybe the following approach is more what you expected. Sorry, that I didn't thought about it last night. But please keep in mind, the var for the toggle state is only available in that view, you can show the status in that view, but you can't really work with it. If you want to (re-)use that information, I'd rather take the alternative from last night (see below).

```
//
//  GreekWordTest.swift
//  GreekWordTest
//
//  Created by Sebastian on 15.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct GreekWords: Codable, Hashable {
    var greekWordArray = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Zeta"]
    // The array data comes from a dynamic .json file
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var greekWords: GreekWords
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(greekWords.greekWordArray, id: \.self) { word in
                GreekWordToggleView(greekWord: word)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct GreekWordToggleView: View {
    
    var greekWord: String
    @State private var wordToggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Toggle(greekWord, isOn: $wordToggle)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

And here the screenshot:

[image: Individual toggles for each row]

ALTERNATIVE:

The approach from last night

```
//
//  GreekWordTest.swift
//  GreekWordTest
//
//  Created by Sebastian on 14.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var greekWordsViewModel = GreekWordsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            GreekWordView(greekWordsViewModel: greekWordsViewModel)
        }
        // For this test I am fetching the data once in the beginning when ContentView apears the first time, later I also added a button to fetch it again, it'll overwrite the existing data. You can also add a logic just to update it, that is up to you and your needs.
        .onAppear(){
            greekWordsViewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}


struct GreekWordView: View {
    @ObservedObject var greekWordsViewModel: GreekWordsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            
            
            ForEach(greekWordsViewModel.greekWordArray.indices, id: \.self){ id in
                Toggle(greekWordsViewModel.greekWordArray[id].name, isOn: $greekWordsViewModel.greekWordArray[id].isOn)
                    .padding()
            }
            
            // Here is the extra button to (re-)fetch the data from the json.
            Button(action: {
                greekWordsViewModel.fetchData()
            }) {
                Text("Fetch Data")
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct GreekWord: Identifiable, Hashable  {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var isOn: Bool
}

class GreekWordsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var greekWordArray: [GreekWord] = []
    
    func fetchData(){
        // As mentioned above, in  his example I empty the array on each new loading event. You can also implement a logic to just update the data.
        greekWordArray = []
        
        let greekWords: [String] = load("greekWordsData.json")
        for greekWord in greekWords {
            greekWordArray.append(GreekWord(name: greekWord, isOn: false))
        }
    }
}
```

For decoding the json, I used the following:

```
//
//  ModelData.swift
//  SwiftTest
//
//  Created by Sebastian Fox on 14.08.22.
//

import Foundation

// This function is used to decode a file with a json. I guess you already created something that is decoding a json according to your need, of course you can still use it. 
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

And finally for testing, I used a very simple greekWordsData.json file that just contains:

```
["Alpha", "Beta", "Delta", "Gamma", "Epsilon", "Zeta"]
```

Here a screenshot:

[image: Alternative: Individual toggles for each row]

Best, Sebastian

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. Absolutely, I see how that can be hard coded. However as I mentioned, this data is dynamic and comes from an ever-evolving .json file. I need the binding to work for the model data. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ScottyA, let me think about it if I find a better solution, but for the moment, I think the way I would go is to fetch the data from the .json and create create the greekWord object (as in my solution). E.g. within the GreekWordsViewModel you get the data from the json and decode it and create the GreekWord object from there and put it into the published (@Publish) greekWordArray. Maybe I can update my answer tomorrow to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I like what you proposed, which might be the solution I go with. In my mind, I assumed the solution would be a super-sleek-Swifty answer and the reason I couldn't figure it out is that I'm still a "green" developer. Grateful for your help.

Comment: Hi @ScottyA, I updated my answer, now it also contains a very simple json, the way I decode it and of course the usage to show the toggle on the view. In the example I am fetching the data when the Content view will be opened, but I also added a button to load it. At the moment it is configured to overwrite the data within the array on each fetch event, but you can also change the logic to update/add data. Best regards, Sebastian

Comment: @ScottyA, maybe it was a bit late (in Germany) last night. I updated my answer again, I added another solution, I guess it is more what you were expecting. Best, Sebastian

Comment: Bingo! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you kindly. I've been reading StackOverflow for months, but since I joined last week and began posting, I've realized how immensely helpful it is to have input from other professionals as I grow. You guys rock!

Comment: Just used this implementation in my solution. Great answer. So glad I found this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
private let tags: [String] = ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3", "Tag4"] // Assuming you have your tags defined
@State private var selectedTags: [String] = []
var switcherView: some View {
VStack {
    ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
        HStack {
            Text(tag)
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#090909"))
                .font(FontType.dmsBold.font(size: 16))
            
            Spacer()
            
            Toggle("", isOn: Binding(
                get: {
                    self.selectedTags.contains(tag)
                },
                set: { newValue in
                    if newValue {
                        self.selectedTags.append(tag)
                    } else {
                        self.selectedTags.removeAll { $0 == tag }
                    }
                }
            ))
            .labelsHidden()
            .tint(Color(hex: "#349760"))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Exemple to used Binding {get, set}

Answer (score -1):

My way is to create "fake toggles" based on real toggles that works as toggles :D

> This is necessary to avoid iteration by indexes(like in another answer). Iteration by indexes can be a cause of view refresh issues.

you need to:

1. create wrapper around your object with "checked" property

```
public struct ToggleModel<T>: Hashable where T: Hashable {
    public static func == (lhs: ToggleModel<T>, rhs: ToggleModel<T>) -> Bool {
        lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(item)
    }
    
    public let item: T
    public var checked: Bool = true
    
    public init(_ item: T, checked: Bool = true) {
        self.item = item
        self.checked = checked
    }
}
```

2. generate array with wrapper-models
3. apply it into your view and make clickable overlay with custom tap func that correctly work with click

```
struct MyData: View {
    @State private var questModels = ["quest 1", "quest 2", "quest 3"].map{ ToggleModel($0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(questModels, id: \.self) { itemModel in
                Toggle(itemModel.item, isOn: .constant(itemModel.checked))
                    .overlay(Color.clickableAlpha)
                    .onTapGesture {
                         guard let idx = questModels.firstIndex(of: itemModel) else { return }
                         questModels[idx].checked.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

clickableAlpha here is:

```
public extension Color {
    init(rgbaHex: UInt32) {
        self.init(
            red:      Double((rgbaHex >> 24) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            green:    Double((rgbaHex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            blue:     Double((rgbaHex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            opacity:  Double(rgbaHex & 0xFF) / 256.0
        )
    }
    
    static var clickableAlpha: Color { get { return Color(rgbaHex: 0x01010101) } }
}
```

Comment: @SebastianFox that's my minus of another answer. Troubles of another answer is: 1) in first solution you cannot use values of toggles. It's ABSOLUTELY USELESS as you need to use data but you have no ability to do this. It's insane to have view without ability of data usage. Just garbage in the answer 2) second solution is not universal - you need to create new toggle model for each new situation 3) both of solutions is larger amount of code than my solution.

Comment: 4) another information garbage in the answer - other people don't need code of json decoding in the answer. They are search for solution to use array of toggles values. 5) in my answer you can use dynamic amount of elements without any troubles. In my answer there are no warning ```don't use indicies in ForEach```. In another answer you will get warnings and troubles of view refreshes in case of dynamic amount of elements (some elements may be not shown at all - that's why those warning shown). ***So difference between both answers is HUGE***

Comment: @SebastianFox I wish that users were required to give an explanation as to why something would be downvoted.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA I agree, from my end, at least the first solution was an explanation why the initial approach by ScottyA was not working and it is just a way to make the initial approach work regardless of how to go on from there.

Comment: @ScottyA that's true

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA Btw. thanks for clarification. Just one thing, could you please show the entire code. If I just do copy and paste the published one, it doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA one more thing, your struct ToggleModel is in my case the the struct GreekWord. The entire ViewModel stuff just came in because of the requirement to load values from the JSON. If we just use an array of values in my approach, and we would remove the entire JSON and ViewModel stuff (including the fetchData button) the difference in the length of code wouldn't be that big. In addition to that, could you please add your solution in how to load the JSON data which (I'd assume) is coming from a server and was a requirement from the beginning.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA sorry, that I already have the next thing. In your ForEach loop you are assigning a constant value to the toggle, without the extra '.onTapGesture' the toggle would be useless. From my perspective using a tillage that is not able to toggle without extra code is non-sense. Even if it is not directly on each iteration of the ForEach, you are using the index as well in the extra '.onTapGesture'.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA The more I think about, the approaches are more similar as expected, I use the index in each iteration to have a binding to the object, to use the toggle directly, in your approach, you make the Toggle useless and change the value via an index to have your own toggle event, to just use the Toggle element as some kind of label image.

Comment: @SebastianFox read  "5)" from my previous comment why using ".indicies" is bad idea.

Comment: @SebastianFox I have fixed my answer, now you're able to copy-paste code from the answer

Comment: @SebastianFox - you're absolutely right when you're telling that original question is telling about json, but main question is related to dynamic list of toggles. Any person that will search this will be in another/different situation. In my case I have search for this question without requesting data from server, as example. No matter where from data was gotten, but there is a matter how to do set of toggles based on array of ANY data.

Comment: And to find final solution in your answer is much harder than to find solution in my answer - because of information garbage (not sure that this term is exist in English, but I hope you understand what I mean when I use this term)